# Flask url processors

Tags: url, flask, routes, internationalization

I'm building flask web app for two languages.
I read https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/urlprocessors/#internationalized-application-urls

```
 from flask import Flask, g

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.url_defaults
def add_language_code(endpoint, values):
    if 'lang_code' in values or not g.lang_code:
        return
    if app.url_map.is_endpoint_expecting(endpoint, 'lang_code'):
        values['lang_code'] = g.lang_code

@app.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_lang_code(endpoint, values):
    g.lang_code = values.pop('lang_code', None)

@app.route('/<lang_code>/')
def index():
    ...

@app.route('/<lang_code>/about')
def about():
    ...
```

However, I couldn't understand what "values" exactly mean.
Also I ran the code, but it gave the following error.

g.lang_code = values.pop('lang_code', None)

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pop'

Can you give any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was working off the same tutorial as you and found that things worked fine with a trailing slash (such as `example.com/en/`), but I was getting the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pop'` error when trying to load routes without entering the trailing slash in my browser (such as `example.com/en`).

By default Flask is going to redirect the non-trailing-slash URL to a trailing-slash anyways, so I just resolved this by adding the bare minimum to avoid the error:

```
@app.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_lang_code(endpoint, values):
    if values is None:
        values = {}
    g.lang_code = values.pop('lang_code', None)
```